# Magento2 redirecting to homepage

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect, home-page

Can anyone let me know why below code of refer URL redirects to homepage, instead of last page visited in controller ?

This happens only in live website, beta website works perfect:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
return $resultRedirect;
```

Comment: Check your cookie setting at live system

Comment: do you mean this setting?
Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled